# Delete all string after last matching words

Tags: shell

I want to delete all string after last where condition

My input is

```
DELETE FROM abc T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cdef T2 WHERE T1.a=T2.b)
```

Want the output as

```
DELETE FROM abc T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cdef T2 WHERE
```

i have tried it with sed command as

```
output=`echo DELETE FROM abc T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cdef T2
WHERE T1.a=T2.b) | sed -n -e 's/[Ww][Hh][Ee][Rr][Ee].*//p'`
```

but i got output as

> DELETE FROM abc T1

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162377/sed-remove-the-very-last-occurrence-of-a-string-a-comma-in-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`, using BRE:

```
sed 's/\(.*WHERE\).*/\1/;s/\(.*where\).*/\1/;' <<< "DELETE FROM abc T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cdef T2 WHERE T1.a=T2.b)"
```

With GNU `sed`, using the `i` (for case insensitive) modifier:

```
sed 's/\(.*where\).*/\1/i' <<< "DELETE FROM abc T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cdef T2 WHERE T1.a=T2.b)"
```

or the alternation `|` operator:

```
sed -r 's/(.*(where|WHERE)).*/\1/i' <<< "DELETE FROM abc T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cdef T2 WHERE T1.a=T2.b)"
```

**output:**

```
DELETE FROM abc T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cdef T2 WHERE
```